# how to get an element from a list using maybe

Tags: haskell, recursion

i am trying to implement the following function, which should result the nth element from a list, in case it exists. in case it does not, it should result in nothing:

```
hello :: [a] -> Integer -> Maybe a
```

this function should be resulting in:

```
hello [1..10] 4
Just 5
```

and

```
hello [1..10] 10
Nothing
```

this is what I did so far:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

hello :: [a] -> Integer -> Maybe a
[]     hello _ = Nothing
(x:xs) hello 0 = Just x
(x:xs) hello i = xs hello (i-1)
```

it is saying 'parse error in pattern (x:xs)'
i find it hard to fix this error as I am new to programming
hence any hints would be much appreciated

Comment: You did not specify what the function is supposed to do, you only give a few examples.

Comment: Hint: `hello [] _ = Nothing`

Comment: You're mixing up the order of parameter and function name. Where you have `[] hello _` it should be `hello [] _` (function name comes first, unless you're defining an infix operator).

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, but confused a bit first argument of a function and the function name. The version of your function's implementation, that doesn't raise syntax errors is:

```
hello :: [a] -> Integer -> Maybe a
hello [] _ = Nothing
hello (x:xs) 0 = Just x
hello (x:xs) n = hello xs (n-1)
```

Comment: thank you. after fixing this code the compiler is saying: Ambiguous occurrence ‘Maybe’. It could refer to either ‘Prelude.Maybe’ or ‘Hello.Maybe’. It is showing this for Maybe, Nothing and Just?

Comment: @gewissen That is because you redefined the `Maybe` type in your file. You don't have to do that, just use the standard definition.

Comment: yea, or exclude Prelude, but it's unnecessary

Comment: @gewissen Or even more alternatively, just rename your definitions to something like `MyMaybe`, `MyNothing` and `MyJust` if you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to define `hello` using infix notation, you need to enclose `hello` in backquotes:

```haskell
hello :: [a] -> Integer -> Maybe a
[]     `hello` _ = Nothing
(x:xs) `hello` 0 = Just x
(_:xs) `hello` i = xs `hello` (i-1)
```

Otherwise, you have to use the regular prefix notation for non-operator functions:

```haskell
hello :: [a] -> Integer -> Maybe a
hello []     _ = Nothing
hello (x:xs) 0 = Just x
hello (_:xs) i = hello xs (i-1)
```